# Azure Text Analytics - Topics returned still include phrases in stopPhrases

Tags: azure, text-analysis

When calling the API for topic detection, I submit as part of the request a list of stopPhrases as in below example.  However, the successful response I get still includes topics specifically defined in the stopPhrases.  I use the format as Microsoft defined - like below.  The only difference is I put the stopPhrases and stopWords at the top of the JSON string.

`{
     "documents": [
         {
             "id": "1",
             "text": "First document"
         },
         ...
         {
             "id": "100",
             "text": "Final document"
         }
     ],
     "stopWords": [
         "issue", "error", "user"
     ],
     "stopPhrases": [
         "Microsoft", "Azure"
     ]
 }`

Comment: The topic detection capability was deprecated last month. Luis Cabrera,
Text Analytics Program Manager